# 'IF' Condition for start variable only if they are initialized

Tags: javascript, android, variables, gps, coordinates

I have this problem , I have 4 variable to be initialized with GPS coordinates, and once loaded , I have to go be in another script .
The first 2 are loaded immediately , and another 2 after 4 seconds , as here :

```
(function(){
        function onSuccess(position) {

         poslat = position.coords.latitude;                   
         poslon = position.coords.longitude;                  

        console.log('latitudine1 ' + poslat);
        console.log('longitudine1 ' + poslon);

        //after 4 second

        setTimeout(function(){

         poslt = position.coords.latitude;                    
         posln = position.coords.longitude;                    
         speed = position.coords.speed;
         alt = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
         precisione = position.coords.accuracy;
         document.getElementById("altitudine").innerHTML = alt;
         document.getElementById("precision").innerHTML = precisione;
         var speedfix = speed * 3.6;
         var speedfixed = speedfix.toFixed(3);
         document.getElementById("sped").innerHTML = speedfixed;

        console.log('latitudine2 ' + poslt);
        console.log('longitudine2 ' + posln);
        //alert("Passed 4 second");
         },4000);
```

If you know how to create a condition 'if' for doing this (example : when all coordinates variable are initialize, doing this) ?Because GPS is always loaded with different times and it's slow
Thanks.

Something so,i tried

```
if (poslat != null || poslon != null || poslt != null || posln != null )
{
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work with wi-fi/3g connection.

```
 if ((poslat != null) && (poslon != null) && (poslt != null) && (posln != null))
           {
             ready();
           }else{
           alert('GPS / Connessione debole.. ')

           }
```

but when I try it only with the GPS ( where there is no signal ) does not work.
Why ? I think when the GPS loaded , the variable does not have the value " null "
but which ??